# Disable shipping method based on category

Tags: category, checkout, shipping-methods

Currently I'm working on a new shipping method. I want this shipping method (pick-up at store) to be enabled for all categories, except for the category 'sale'. By category I mean the categories you can create in the backend of Magento, under the tab 'Products'. I did some research, but can't find a working code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,you need to  track how  `a cart item  is cart from Sales Category` as magento system does not `save the category details at checkout relate tables.`

As per as `magento system collectRates` function of s`hipping method is responsible for  a shipping will shown or not on Checkout`.

There `collectRates` method you can `get cart item details on`  by

```
if ($request->getAllItems()) {
                foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product=$item->getProduct();
        }
    }
```

**Solution:**
 need to save `category id`  at `sales_flat_quote_item` table during cart then  on basic of  `this field disable  shipment method.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite or copy to the local code pool the following class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`

To rewrite:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode)) {
           return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAvailable($carrierCode)
    {
        if ($carrierCode !== 'your carrier code') {
            return true;
        }

        $quoteItemList = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($quoteItemList as $quoteItem) {
            // Retrieve category ids
            $categoryIdList = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
            foreach ($categoryIdList as $categoryId) {
                if ($categoryId == 'your category id'){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to copy the following class to the local code pool, find the method `collectCarrierRates` and add the following lines before the core code.

```
if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode)) {
    return $this;
}
```

Add new method `_isAvailable`, you can use the same method as indicated above for the rewriting case.

You can move the hardcoded category ids dependency to config and make it user friendly.

Comment: This gives an error: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping' not found in code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php. And where do I add the new method _isAvailable?

Comment: I guess you want to use second solution
**copy to the local code pool**
So please copy `app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Shipping.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Shipping\Model\Shipping.php` and make changes in this new file.
**Remember!** Never edit Magento core files

Comment: @Neklo.com Thanks man ...its working fine you solved my problem....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link first:

- http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-filter-shipping-method-in-onepage-checkout/

In function _checkCarrierAvailability(), you need to change the logic in following manner.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item)
{
$categoryIds = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds(); // returns category ids from product
  foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)
   {
     if($categoryId == ***SALE CATEGORY ID***){
         if($carrierCode == ***pick-up at store METHOD CODE***){ #Hide Flat Rate for non logged in customers
            return false;
        }
      }
   }
}
```